# T-Sql query for the situation - Need a departmentID with max number of employees?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, max

let's say employee table has employee details and deptId of the employee.
to get the number of employees in each deptid,

```
select deptId, COUNT(*) from employee group by deptId;
```

question is: to get the deptId having max number of employees of the above result set,

`select Top 1 deptId, COUNT(*) from employee group by deptId order by 2 desc`

(2-ref to second column in the query list) - will do.. but

Is there anyway to avoid ordering this set? or better way of writing this sql,

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why is ordering the set bad?

Comment: If there are two departments that tie for the maximum number of employees, what do you expect / want?

Answer (score 0):

> If you just want the `MAX` number of employees within a department, you can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1  DepartmentID, 
       COUNT(EmployeeID) 
FROM EmployeeTable
GROUP BY DepartmentID
ORDER BY COUNT(EmployeeID) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any ordering, it is hard, but try

```
   Select deptId, cnt
   From (Select deptId, count(*) cnt
         from employee
         Group By deptId) Z
   Where cnt = (Select Max(cnt) 
                From (Select deptId, count(*) cnt
                      From employee
                      Group By deptId) ZZ)
```